# powershell where-object specific number of numeric characters

Tags: parsing, powershell, object, syntax, where-clause

I looked through some similar question but couldn't find an example of this sort of logic- what im looking for is a way to parse through a large return of usernames in powershell. User names that are not service accounts or kiosks have a specific naming convention of 6 grouped numeric characters: for example- username123456. I was thinking there has to be a way of using the where-object command but can't find anything on the syntax on technet or other PS resources. The one liner to get a return from the local domain is:

```
Search-ADAccount -PasswordNeverExpires |  Select-Object Name, Enabled
```

This returns a list of domain accounts that have the password set to never expire. I want to only see the ones with the above naming convention ^^ I know you can achieve this with regex but my regex is quite rusty---if it can be done with where-object that would be optimal. I also looked into using pattern, but it seems to be for more complex returns than this... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are they under a specific OU? You could then use the `-Searchbase` parameter to limit the scope of the search to that OU.

Otherwise, Regex is probably going to be a good option to accomplish this.

```
Search-ADAccount -PasswordNeverExpires |  Select-Object Name, Enabled | Where {
    $_.name -match '\D\d{6}$'
}
```

Comment: You're making an assumption that the beginning of all the user names are `[a-z]*`. You should probably just drop that and keep the `\d{6}$` part since we don't know exact details of the user names aside from the fact that they end in 6 digits.

Comment: This was perfect! I need to get back into regex- powershells where-object has spoiled me. thanks boeprox! +1 to you.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician You are correct. It is an assumption based on the provided username as an example in the question. I'll update my answer to remove that assumption.

Comment: You need `\D\d{6}$` to does not match strings with more than six digits at the end.